# Can one use data already fetched by Apple Stocks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, iwork-numbers

I have this Home Office edition of MS Excel for Mac and I was playing with Google Sheets earlier, chiefly with the `GOOGLEFINANCE` function, when it occurred to me that Apple Numbers might have a similar function. And indeed it does, but Numbers is kind of clumsy and I've never really managed to get used to it.

Then, it occurred to me that Apple Numbers is probably tapping into the Apple Stocks financial information. So, presumably there is an API there in the OS somewhere and they talk to each other and the Numbers spreadsheet simply observes some process behind the scenes.

It stands to reason, therefore, that if my suspicion is correct, one could get MS Excel to observe the same process or use the same API and fetch the same information.

Has anyone tried that yet? Can we use some other means of obtaining data, say, an automator job, or a macro, or something along those lines, and get the valuations that Apple Stocks is using?

Answer (score 2):

Apple Numbers is using a web API to get stock information, not talking to something in the OS. Numbers used to (still does?) use yahoo finance's API specifically.

Office 365 Excel also has built-in stock information with the Stocks data type and `STOCKHISTORY` function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-a-stock-quote-e5af3212-e024-4d4c-bea0-623cf07fbc54 . Excel currently uses Refinitiv's API to provide stock info.

There are other free stock price APIs like https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/ for example, and some even have excel plugins or code samples which make them easier to use.